# Overriding constants in derived classes in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, constants

In C# can a constant be overridden in a derived class? I have a group of classes that are all the same bar some constant values, so I'd like to create a base class that defines all the methods and then just set the relevant constants in the derived classes. Is this possible?

I'd rather not just pass in these values to each object's constructor as I would like the added type-safety of multiple classes (since it never makes sense for two objects with different constants to interact).

Answer (score 70):

It's not a constant if you want to override it ;). Try a virtual read-only property (or protected setter).

Read-only property:

```
public class MyClass {
    public virtual string MyConst { get { return "SOMETHING"; } }
}
...
public class MyDerived : MyClass {
    public override string MyConst { get { return "SOMETHINGELSE"; } }
}
```

Protected setter:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string MyConst { get; protected set; }

    public MyClass() {
        MyConst = "SOMETHING";
    }
}

public class MyDerived : MyClass {
    public MyDerived() {
        MyConst = "SOMETHING ELSE";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Unfortunately constants cannot be overridden as they are not virtual members.  Constant identifiers in your code are replaced with their literal values by the compiler at compile time.

I would suggest you try to use an abstract or virtual property for what you would like to do.  Those are virtual and as such can (must, in the case of an abstract property) be overridden in the derived type.

Answer (score 9):

Constants marked with `const` cannot be overridden as they are substituted by the compiler at compile time.

But regular static fields assigned to constant values can. I've had such a case just now:

```
class Columns
{
    public static int MaxFactCell = 7;
}

class Columns2 : Columns
{
    static Columns2()
    {
        MaxFactCell = 13;
    }
}
```

If I just redefined the `MaxFactCell` field in the derived class instead, polymorphism wouldn't work: code using `Columns2` as `Columns` would not see the overriding value.

If you need to restrict write (but not read) access to the field, using `readonly` would prohibit redefining it in `Columns2`. Make it a property instead, that's slightly more code:

```
class Columns
{
    static Columns()
    {
        MaxFactCell = 7;
    }            
    public static int MaxFactCell { get; protected set; }
}

class Columns2 : Columns
{
    static Columns2()
    {
        MaxFactCell = 13;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) of Columns2 is called before accessing `Columns2.MacFactCell`, you may get 7 as a result. Also, once the `Columns2` constructor has been called (for example when creating the first `Columns2` instance), `Columns.MacFactCell` will read 13.

Comment: @marapet How so? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors, "\[static constructor\] is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced." -- which is what happens here. Neither https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members says anything about the two classes' members sharing the same space.

Comment: @marapet I do see that with VS2017's `csc`, it's as you say (the code was written for VS2008 and .NET 3.5), but it seems to be directly contradicting the docs!

Comment: Maybe something changed somewhere along the way... `MaxFactCell` seems to be considered a member of `Columns`, even when accessed via `Columns2.MaxFactCell`, therefore the `Columns2` static constructor is not called, which then is consistent with the documentation. This makes sense because you can't do inheritance with static classes. When Columns2 inherits Columns only _instances_ of Columns2 are concerned.

Answer (score 7):

Edit: This can have unexpected behaviour, see Shai Petel's remark below.

You can hide the inherited constant in a derived class by declaring the new constant `new`. I'm not sure this is a good practice, though.

```
class A
{
    protected const int MyConst = 1;
}

class B : A
{
    new private const int MyConst = 2;
}
```

Comment: This one would be a nice one :)

Comment: Didn't try it, but would probably not work when casting to the base class. So, if you have object of type B, when you cast/treat it as object of type A theoretically it would return 1 and not 2, since this does not override the member. So, this would be an unsafe practice - keep that in mind.

Comment: @ShaiPetel That's a good remark. I tried that. You cannot reference a constant from an instance (such as `instanceA.MyConst`), you need to write `A.MyConst`, which makes it clear. However, if class `A` has a method using `MyConst` and the method is called from `B`, it uses `MyConst` value from `A`.

Answer (score 3):

to Work off dten + Tracker1's answer but updated for c# 6

```
public class MyClass {
    public virtual string MyConst =>"SOMETHING";
}
...
public class MyDerived : MyClass {
    public override string MyConst  =>"SOMETHING ELSE";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can force derived classes to have a value for a constant (well, a read-only property)

- Make an interface containing a read-only property.
- Put that interface on the base class.

Example:

```
   public interface IHasConstant
   {
        string MyConst { get; }
   }
```