# How to override constants derived classes?

Tags: c#

CODE :

```
public class A {
    public const int beingSupportedRate = 0;
}

 public partial class B : A {
    public const int beingSupportedRate = 1;

}
```

I want it as explicitly as a const int because of performance.
Putting virtual in front of `class A` variable `beingSupportedRate` causes compiler error following :

`The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding constants in derived classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770437/overriding-constants-in-derived-classes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I believe you misunderstood the point of polymorphism in object-oriented programming.

Constants, fields and variables are just a *storage* (well, references, but I'm talking from the conceptual point of view).

Polymorphism is about changing the behavior of *something*. Overriding a constant couldn't be *changing a behavior* but *changing its value*.

Another point is a constant is *static*, thus it doesn't belong to an instance but there's an immutable single value in the `AppDomain` and it survives for the application life-cycle.

With the above statement, why you would want to override a constant like an instance member? Do you imagine the next situation?

```
public class A 
{
      public virtual const int Some = 1;
}

public class B : A
{
      public override const int Some = 2;
}

public class C : A
{
     // No override here!
}

int valueOfSomeConstant = C.Some;
```

Hold! If a constant is static, `C.Some` would be `2` even if `C` does override no constant!

Some quote from your question:

> I want it as explicitly as a const int because of performance. [...]

This has only an answer: the premature optimization is the devil of any software development.

[As Jon Skeet said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15158508/3195477), this is going to be the least of your issues.

Answer (score 14):

You should use the `new` keyword to explicitly hide the inherited member:

```
public class A
{
    public const int beingSupportedRate = 0;
}

public class B : A
{
    public new const int beingSupportedRate = 1;
}
```

Remember that you cannot access the constant member from an instance.

```
Console.WriteLine(A.beingSupportedRate);
Console.WriteLine(B.beingSupportedRate);
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

There are some problems that you should consider when using this solution. Take the following console program, for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        a.GetBeingSupportRate();
        b.GetBeingSupportRate();
        c.GetBeingSupportRate();

        Console.Read();
    }

    public class A
    {
        public const int beingSupportedRate = 0;
        public void GetBeingSupportRate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(beingSupportedRate);
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public new const int beingSupportedRate = 1;

    }

    public class C : B
    {

    }
}
```

This will output `0` for all three class instances, since the inherited method uses the constant value in A. This means you will have to override all methods that reference the constant.

A preferred approach is to use an interface with a property that must be implemented and not use constants for this purpose.

Comment: This is a bad solution because if some class `A` member access the base constant, when some may call a member inherited from `A`, the whole member will access the non-reused identifier of the constant!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Can you put that in different wording? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @JohnWillemse Summary: this isn't an override. It's an identifier reuse. Just do your own test code and implement a method "DoStuff" returning the value of the `beingSupportedRate` constant on `A` class and create an instance of class `B`. Now call `DoStuff`. Now do the whole `Console.WriteLine(b.DoStuff())`. What's going to print?

Comment: @JohnWillemse http://pastebin.com/MhyPrUHm Check this code. This shows how wrong is your answer (in my opinion).

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I know it's not an override, that's why I said he should hide the member. I'm aware of the problems that may arise, and I'm of the opinion that he should not be using constants at all, but I answered the question to fulfill the requirement. I agree with you ;)

Comment: @JohnWillemse Ok ok, but I'd like to make you a small suggestion: could you make a note about this problem in your answer? You can use the code I gave you to demonstrate the issue! :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I cannot access PasteBin from work, unfortunately, but I'll edit my answer to reflect the idea.

Comment: @JohnWillemse Great! Now your answer is complete :D

Comment: You enlightened me on the fact that new inheritance modifier can be used on a const member also. +1.

Answer (score 9):

Fields (including constants) can't be virtual. That has nothing to do with it being a constant... it's just the way fields work... although the fact that constants are implicitly static makes it even *less* feasible, as it were.

If you want polymorphic behaviour, it *has* to be via an instance member which is a property, method or event.

As an aside, I *strongly* suspect your "I want it as `const` for performance reasons" justification is bogus micro-optimization. It's not even clear how you're using this, but I very much doubt that you've tried it as a non-constant and proved that it's too slow.

Comment: I have not proved it. Just back to my knowledge about C++ made me think run-time variables are much slower.

Comment: @Mahdi: a) this isn't C++; b) in *most* cases it's not going to matter anyway. Given that you haven't even got the behaviour you want *working* yet, performance is the least of your issues.

Comment: @JonSkeet How would I implement type-dependent constants in an inheritance hierarchy? Let's say I have some classes for UI controls which all have some default dimensions (i.e. a button has a different default size than a panel). Some derive from one another but their default dimensions are only dependent on the control type (which is the class type). My guess would be a public static readonly property or "this is just bad design" :D.

Comment: Oh I forgot. The reason why I need this as a public constant is because I want to use it like `Button.DefaultWidth` or `Panel.DefaultWidth` in other code segments as well. Things like `int.MaxValue` comes to mind in this context but `Int32` is lucky enough to have no base class with a `MaxValue` constant/property as well. :)

Comment: @RobertS.: I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details, including what you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

Constants cannot be overridden, they are constant.

If you want this value to be alterable by extension then you'll need to use something less *constant*, with a nature of being changed per context, such as an `abstract` element to implement or `virtual` to override.

Comment: I think that missed the point that *no* fields can be overridden.

Answer (score 3):

U Can do this i guess:

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual Int32 beingSupportedRate
    { 
        get { return 0; }
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override Int32 beingSupportedRate 
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. however this is not a const. it's a run-time property.