# C# Class Inheretance - Possible to change a variable in subclass?

Tags: c#

I'm making a very basic game in C# and using a class diagram as a guide.

I have a `Building` class and a `Room` Class.
On my diagram it says that `Room` inherits from `Building`, So `Building` is the super class in this case.

My `Building` Class contains the set-up array to hold the rooms

```
public class building // Building Object Class
{
    const int SizeConst = 4; 
    private int[,] Cells; 

    public int[,] create() 
    {
        Cells = new int[SizeConst, SizeConst]; 
        return Cells;
    }
}
```

`Room` is exactly the same although it would be nice to be able to change the size constant indipendantly.

For example, The `Size` Constant of the `Building` could stay at 4 giving 25 rooms. But what if I wanted to change the `Size` constant for `Room` to 5 to get 36 movement spaces?

Comment: You can change constant to virtual getter with hardcoded value. You can find how to do that there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770437/overriding-constants-in-derived-classes-in-c-sharp

Comment: Got to say Room inherits from building seems a bad move. Both having a common ancestor, or using an interface, should leave you with a better a design. Buildings have rooms, doesn't mean rooms are buildings.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'm pretty new to UML and class diagrams and find them incredibly confusing. Do you think they should be separate objects entirely?

Comment: Can't say from here, but the rule for inheritance versus aggregation is Is a ? a ? or has a ? a ?. So is a room a building? No, Does a building have a room? Yes. What common behaviours persuaded you to inheritance. They are both locations? If so perhaps Building and room should be a Location, or perhaps they should both implement ILocatable

Answer (score 0):

You can't override a constant (that wouldn't make it a constant anymore).
You should provide a virtual getter or a method:

```
    public class building // Building Object Class
    {
        protected virtual int Size{ get;}
        private int[,] Cells; 

        public int[,] create() 
        {
            Cells = new int[Size, Size]; 
            return Cells;
         }
    }

    public class Room
    {
        protected virtual int Size
        {
             get
             {
                 // return custom value here
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot change the **constant**, but instead of this I advice you use polymorphism and create virtual property or method that will return the desired value.

For example:

```
public class Building
{
    public virtual int CellCount { get { return 5; } }
}

public class Room : Building
{
    public override int CellCount { get { return 6; } }
}
```

Hope this helps.